Isolating a variable on one side in a hyperbolic equation
I am dealing with a hyperbolic equation in desmos. I need to shade area under the curve defined by the given equation but for that I need to isolate one variable h on one side of the equation.
$$
6 \tfrac{h}{B}\cdot \left(\tfrac{h}{B} + \tfrac{k}{L} \right) = 3\tfrac{h}{B} - \tfrac{k}{L}
$$
Edit:

I want to shade the white area between two hyperbolic curves in desmos. Both curves can be obtained from the above equation. 2nd equation can be obtained by the same equation but by interchanging h/B by k/L. I can isolate k in the equation but cannot do the same for h.
By the way, I can shade the area above and below the curve but cannot shade the area between the curves.
To obtain the area between the curve I have to write equation in form displayed below.
$${equation}<h<\frac{\left(3\frac{k}{L}-6\frac{k}{L}\frac{k}{L}\right)}{\left(6\frac{k}{L}\frac{1}{B}+\frac{1}{B}\right)} $$
Where "equation" is the equation where h is isolated on one side in the above equation.
If you have another workaround you can share it.

Please latexify your equation

Please show some of your own thoughts

Moreover. $$h=B/2-x$$ and $$k=L/2-y$$

Setting $x=h/B$ and $y=k/L$ your equation becomes:
$$6x(x+y)=3x-y$$
that is:
$$6x^2+3(2y-1)x+y=0$$
which you can solve for $x$ as usual:
$$x={-3(2y-1)\pm\sqrt{9(2y-1)^2-24y}\over12}.$$
As you want $0\le x\le1/6$ for $0\le y\le1/6$, we must take the "$-$" case and finally get:
$$x={-3(2y-1)-\sqrt{36y^2-60y+9}\over12}.$$
